# Can't get breakpoints to work in WebStorm for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, debugging, webstorm

Most likely a really stupid but completely frustrating question...  Do I need to do something 'special' to enable break points with WebStorm?

I have a ton of experience with PyCharm and it was never an issue.  Click in the left panel and get a red dot.  Run code in debug mode and code stops.  Doesn't seem to work for me in the trial version of WebStorm.  I get the red dot but the breakpoint never trips in debug mode.

I have Googled and ChatGPT'ed and nothing.  Only reference is to a 'check' on the red dot to indicate that breakpoint is enabled but can't get that to happen.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is the code you're trying to stop at a breakpoint at frontend or backend code?

Comment: Simple front end code.

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {

        console.log(`Page loaded`);

        // Initialize the tab component
        $('#myTabs a').on('click', function(e) {...

Comment: Front end breakpoints are finnicky. They require Webstorm establishing a Websocket connection with the browser. I don't have Webstorm handy (I only have a work license), but there's a way of launching the browser when you launch your code, and that's how you need to do it iirc.

Comment: Trying to break on the console.log as a test.

Comment: So yes, for frontend debugging, it is special, because Webstorm needs to establish a communication channel with the browser, since it's ultimately the browser that's stopping at the breakpoint. Debugging backend code will work like you expect though.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful!  Do I need to change the default server port 63342?  Have done some searching but don't see what I need to do to fix with Chrome.

Comment: I don't use Webstorm's frontend debugging, so I'm not sure. The way our system is set up, having a websocket connection from the IDE to the browser is problematic. To do frontend debugging, I just use the Dev Tools in the browser. If you use source maps, it's really not that much harder once you learn how to find the code you want to set a breakpoint at.

Comment: Thanks!  Sorry for the obvious noob miss.

Answer (score 1):

To debug frontend code run in browser, you need using a [JavaScript Debug](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2023.2/run-debug-configuration-javascript-debug.html) run configuration with your app URL. Please see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2023.2/debugging-javascript-in-chrome.html for instructions